# select2 - Dropdown appearing when removing selection from multiselect

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm using a select2 multi-value select box, which is working very well except for a minor issue: when I click the "x" to remove something that has already been selected, the dropdown menu pops up. The selection is successfully removed, but I would like for the dropdown to not appear when removing something.

Here's a snippet of html output:

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;">
    <span class="selection">
        <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" tabindex="0" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="select2-location-results">
            <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
                <li class="select2-selection__choice">
                    <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>
                    1
                </li>
                <li class="select2-selection__choice">
                    <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>
                    2
                </li>
                <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
                    <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="-1" role="textbox" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

The only relevant information I could find is [this github issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/287) but that's supposedly already fixed.